# Scale output of FFT (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, dft

I am doing some Fourier transforms of audio (.wav) data using the FFT command in MATLAB. The input values are numbers between -1.0 and 1.0

My understanding is that after taking the absolute value (modulus) of the output of the FFT, I should get values that have units of amplitude, but the actual values are on the order of thousands. This doesn't make sense as theoretically I should be able to sum the Fourier components to get the original signal back. I feel like the output should then also be between 0 and 1, so what's up here? My guess is that the FFT algorithm blows it out of proportion but I'm not sure what value to use to scale it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FFT is an algorithm for computing the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT). The [inverse DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition) (IDFT) has a 1/*N* scaling factor in its definition. Perhaps that's what's confusing you. From the Wikipedia:

- DFT (from finite sequence *x* to Fourier coefficients *X*):

  [image]
- IDFT (from *X* back to *x*):

  [image]

So, just apply `ifft` to the result of `fft` and you'll get the original result. For example:

```
>> x = linspace(-1,1,5)
x =
   -1.0000   -0.5000         0    0.5000    1.0000

>> y = fft(x)
y =
        0            -1.2500 + 1.7205i  -1.2500 + 0.4061i  -1.2500 - 0.4061i  -1.2500 - 1.7205i

>> abs(y)
ans =
         0    2.1266    1.3143    1.3143    2.1266 %// note values greater than 1

>> ifft(y)
ans =
   -1.0000   -0.5000    0.0000    0.5000    1.0000
```

In fact, the IDFT can be [expressed in terms of the DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Expressing_the_inverse_DFT_in_terms_of_the_DFT) applying complex conjugation and the referred scaling factor. Denoting the DFT by *F*, the IDFT by *F*<sup>-1</sup> and complex conjugate by *,

[image]

In the above example,

```
>> 1/numel(y) * conj(fft(conj(y)))
ans =
   -1.0000   -0.5000    0.0000    0.5000    1.0000
```

Comment: Of course, an alternate (and equally valid) definition has a `sqrt(1/N)` term in both DFT and IDFT -- which probably gives the results that OP is expecting

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point. But 1-scaling for DFT and 1/N-scaling for IDFT is the most common definition, at least in my experience

Comment: I think I understand that there's a distortion of the scale due to summing over n for each X_k, but is there a way to recover the proper scaling? That is, if the input was something like a square wave, when done analytically the ouputs would be the odd harmonics with

Comment: **Sorry that comment got posted before it was finished:

Comment: what I meant was: I think I understand that there's a distortion of the scale due to summing over n for each X_k (correct me if this is wrong), but is there a way to recover the "meaningful" scaling? i.e. the proportion in which each fourier component contributes to the signal? If the F.T. were done analytically and the input was a square wave, the output would be the odd harmonics with coefficients (1/n) (maybe I'm also wring about this?) and none of those coefficients would exceed the original amplitude of the function.  So how can I recover that in the DFT?

Comment: To synthesize the signal from its harmonics you use the IDFT (`ifft` function). Look at the IDFT definition: it contains the 1/N scale factor. So, if you want to obtain the sinusoids that when summed reproduce the signal, you need to __scale the output of `fft` by `1/numel(x)`__. (But then you can't simply apply `ifft` to that; you'd need to either multiply back by `numel(x)`, or do the sum of the sinusoids manually without the scaling factor of the IDFT)

Comment: @Luis You have just to divide the FFT results by the number of input samples.

Comment: @HeinzM. That's what I said in my previous comment (in boldface)! "Scale the output of `fft` by `1/numel(x)`"

Comment: Hey all, this seems to be helping. I did a test on a sine wave of amplitude 1 and the max value in the output of the fft was 0.5. Is there any reason that the proper scaling factor could be 2/numel(x)??

Comment: Yes, there is. Note that you have _two_ coefficients with value (approximately) 0,5 in the `fft`. That's because `sin(t) = (exp(1j*t)-exp(-1j*t))/2j`. So the `sin` is the sum of two exponentials, with positive and negative frequencies, each with _half_ amplitude. Same happens for `cos(t)`, or in general `sin(t+phi)`; only the phase of the exponentials changes. Of course, in the DFT the negative frequencies appear in the _upper half_ of the frequency interval, because the spectrum is periodic

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab use the following code to scale from 1 to (roughly) 0.

```
dataDFT=abs(fft(data)); % Take the complex magnitude of the fft of your data
dataDFTScaled=dataDFT/max(dataDFT); % Divide by the maximum value
```

You don't want it to scale to zero because that would make it impossible to view on a log plot.